# Bookmarks on Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bookmarks

From time to time I read very interesting questions and answers and I would like to keep track of them in order to refer to them later. Does this site provide a bookmarking mechanism or something similar that allows a user to store the interesting pages for future access?

Comment: The star on the left, right below the downvote button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea of stackexchange is probably to use "favourites" for this, which [Johannes_B mentioned in his comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7486/bookmarks-in-texstackexchange#comment22375_7486). However I consider them pretty useless (no notification, many false positives...).

Instead I use RSS feeds to keep track of interesting question. At the bottom of every question there is a link "question feed", which can be used to subscribe to this question.

[image]

Notifications etc. are then handled by the program you use to retrieve the feed.

Comment: Is there a way to keep track of just a certain answer though? Or, may I favourite a certain answer for future reference? Thanks!

Comment: @zyy That is not possible (as far as I know)

Comment: That is so said, I will try to feedback to the site.

Answer (score 7):

The way Stack Exchange handles bookmarks is through something called favourites. It's the star just below the question voting buttons:

[image]

Once a question is starred, you'll find it in your favourite's tab (with the URL `//<site>/users/<userid>?tab=favorites`). Updates to favourites are indicated by a boxed number next to the tab when viewing your user profile:

[image]

You can only add *questions* to your list of favourites and this will necessarily include the *answers* associated with it. You can, of course, also *bookmark* any page using your browser's default bookmarking functionality.

References:

- [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/168244)
- [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1569/168244)